# Extjs Message Box Center Align

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, messagebox, text-align

As the title says, I would like the message of Ext.Msg.alert() to in center align. I tried this:

```
 Ext.Msg.alert({
        title: 'Success',
        msg: 'Deleted',
        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
        baseCls: 'msgbox'
    });
```

CSS:

```
 .msgbox {
      text-align: center;
  }
```

It is still on left align. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The displayed text is a displayfield component that has the same size that its text then, even when it is centered, you cannot see it aligned as you want.

So, the solution is to make it bigger. In my example i do it using a css class. Take a look at it:

```
var w = Ext.Msg.alert({
        title: 'Success',
        msg: 'Deleted',
        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
        autoShow: false,
        cls: 'msgbox'    
});

w.down('.displayfield' ).addCls('displayfield-fullsize');
```

and the class is, as you can imagine:

```
.displayfield-fullsize{
       width: 100% !important;
}
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/lontivero/F7HE3/3/
    ​

Comment: was my example useful for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up using some icons to move the message a little bit and would seem center align. Thanks for the reply though.